# Creating a number of figures dependent on user input

Tags: matlab, function, sorting, plot

I'm fairly new to Matlab so any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to write a function using simple logic operators to create a number of 2D scatter graphs, the problem I've been having is that I cannot work out how to use a input from the user (the number of figures) to actually create that number of figures.

*edit (Just for the sake of clarity I'm plotting multiple sets of data ie columns on each figure but the important bit is that there will be multiple figures as the user specifies how many figures they want, this is the bit I cannot understand. I understand how to use hold on to plot more than one graph on each figure but how do I vary the number of figures depending on the input of the user?)

The user inputs are a matrix with dimensions 4000x30 (this will remain constant for my use) and the number of figures (this will change from 1-30) to plot from this data set. Each column represents a different sensor so the columns represent 1 set of data each.

The simpler the answer the better as I'm not a very experienced coder.

Thanks
GibGib

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want to open many figures or a single figure with many subplots?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Im trying to create many figures with a equal number of columns plotted on each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
Data = rand(40,30); %// Just a small data set for testing.

%// Ask user how many figures are desired
prompt = {'Enter desired number of figures:'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'5'};

NumFigures = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);

%// Get # of figures. If the entry is not valid (i.e. remainder of division 30/entry is not 0), ask again.
while rem(size(Data,2),str2double(NumFigures{1})) ~= 0
NumFigures = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
end

    NumFigures = str2double(NumFigures{1}); %// Convert to number
ColPerFig = size(Data,2)/NumFigures; %// Number of columns to plot per figure

ColStart = 1:ColPerFig:size(Data,2) %// Indices of the starting columns to plot
```

ColStart looks like this:

```
ColStart =

     1     7    13    19    25
```

So its easier in the loop to index into `Data` and fetch the appropriate values.

```
%// Plot
for k = 1:NumFigures;    
    hFig(k) = figure;        
    plot(Data(:,ColStart(k):ColStart(k)+ColPerFig-1));
end
```

Comment: This was very helpful! works perfectly when integrated into my code and its simple enough for even me to understand. Thanks accepted this answer, I would vote up if I could!

Comment: Thanks again! Im sure I'll be back at some point with more questions :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like what you are asking is that you have this data matrix M, where the user defines U, and you to plot U number of plots where each plot is the 2D scatter of U columns that corresponds to M?
in that case, will this do?

```
figure;
hold on %is optional depending how you want your plot
for i = 1:U
 plot(M(:,i))
end
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please specify your question further.

Comment: What I was looking for was a way to create multiple figures of number U (in your example) but plotting all of the data in M equally as different plots on those figures. For example if you chose U as 5 as there are 30 columns then there would be 6 columns of data on each figure each one as a separate plot.